# Functions behavior in C++

Tags: c++, function

I have the following code:

```
int Fun(int x, int y)
{
    if(x<y)
        return 1;
}
int main ()
{

    cout<<Fun(6,2)<<endl;
}
```

The output of this code is 6(the value of **x**)!! I don't know why this behavior...Can any one explain to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which compiler and IDE you are using?

Comment: This code should give you warning.

Comment: That's [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). What if the condition in your `if` statement is false? What will be returned then?

Comment: try calling it as Fun(2,6), this will give you some tips

Comment: @pranitkothari: Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @Computer_Engineer Ya, I also check with Visual Studio, and surprised it is not giving error.

Comment: Always enable compiler warnings, and always read (and fix) them.

Answer (score 6):

Here you have an [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) like it has already been said.

As it is stated in the C++11 Standard:

> **6.6.3 The return statement [stmt.return]**
>
> 2. [..] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Explanations:

```
int Fun(int x, int y)
{
    if ( x < y ) // if this condition is false, then no return statement
        return 1;
}
```

How to fix this ?

```
int Fun(int x, int y)
{
    if ( x < y )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;  // <-- Fix the error
}
```

*Note: You compiler should have gave you a **Warning** at least... Did you ignore it ? (something  like **"not all control paths return a value"**)*

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a return statement at the end of Fun

```
int Fun(int x, int y)
{
    if(x<y)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

The 6 you get is just undefined behaviour (you could get anything... even a core dump) for function that should return but it is not returning

Note that the existing return 1 is in the scope of the `if(x<y)` ... since an if without braces { } takes as body one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a return statement at the end of Fun

You are getting `6` because of `Function Prologue and Epilogue`. while calling the function, program will put `6` and `2` into the stack and return value will be kept in `eax` register. so as per my knowledge while comparing the values program would have copied `6` to `eax` register and since you are not returning anything the `eax` register is not getting updated. and the caller program reads the data from `eax` register which is `6`.

Please check this part, I have generated assembly code from your example.

```
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax       //eax has value 6
        cmpl    12(%ebp), %eax
        jge     .L5                //if true (x>y) then jump to .L5
        movl    $1, %eax           //updating eax to 1 if false (x<y)
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        jmp     .L1
.L5:
        jmp     .L4
.L1:
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
.L4:
        leave
        ret                        //returning from function eax still have value 6 as per your code
```